# Changing Appearance of PyQt5 Window Title and Customizing the Window Title

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

The code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import* 
from PyQt5.QtGui import*
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *


class Pencere(QWidget):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 
        self.setGeometry(100,50,1080,1080)   
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("note.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle("M Content Re-Writer")
        
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.texteditor()
        
        vbox2 = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        vbox2.addWidget(self.button, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)
        vbox2.addWidget(self.editor, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        vbox.addWidget(self.widget) 

    def texteditor(self):
        self.editor = QTextEdit()
        self.editor.resize(500, 500) 
        self.editor.move(5,40)
        self.button = QPushButton("re-write")
        self.button.setFont(QFont('Segoe Script', 11))
        self.button.setStyleSheet("border : 2px lemonchiffon;  border-style : solid")
                                   
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.function)
       
    def function(self):
        text = self.editor.toPlainText()             # editor'de yazan yaziyi al
#        path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save File", "", "Text documents (*.txt);All files (*.*)")
        if not text: # == "":
            print("none")
            return
#        else:
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
                        self, 
                        "Save file", 
                        "", 
                        "Text documents (*.txt);All files (*.*)") 
        if path:                        
            with open(path, 'w') as murti:
                murti.write(text)
  

qss = """
#widget {
    border-image: url(2.jpg) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
}
QPushButton {background-color : yellow;}
QPushButton:hover:pressed {background-color: red;}
QPushButton:hover {background-color: #0ff;}

QTextEdit {
    background-image: url("hand.jpeg");
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color:white;
    font-size:24px;
    }

"""     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    demo = Pencere()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hello, How can I make the background of the title of the GUI window appear transparent instead of white? In addition, I want to ask this: How can I change the color and font style of the M Content Re-Writer text in the title? I also added a screenshot to make it better. Thanks for your help.

[image: help]

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot do this directly with pyqt. You need to use Winapi (which is a bit tricky and complicated) or you have to do it custom title bar by creating a borderless window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are modifying the window title so much, I believe it would be helpful to simply remove it create a custom one.

```
self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

This code gets rid of the window frame (which removes the title bar.)

Now, we just need to create our own title bar. This will look something like:

```
self.topMenu = QLabel(self)
self.topMenu.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 60)
self.topMenu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 120);")
```

This code creates a blank bar for everything to rest on.
From here, you just need to create a label for text, followed by three buttons for closing, minimizing, and full screening the window.